# What's the proper way to add users to my site in order to test things?

Tags: wpdb, wp-user-query

I'm new to wordpress.

I'm have my site just running on localhost and want to test some things out with dummy data/made up users.

When I log in to my wordpress database, I see that there is a table already there called `wp_users`

My plan right now is to run a sql script `INSERT` a whole bunch of fake users into the `wp_users` table and start testing the functionality of my site.

My question is, is this the proper way of doing things? Is the wp_users table for admins or people who will edit the site, or is it meant for users who will login to the site?

Sorry if this is a silly question. Thank you!

Comment: You can use this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/fakerpress/

Comment: There are a number of plugins to help create a VOLUME of data, as well as the one above, there is https://wordpress.org/plugins/demo-data-creator/. HOWEVER the only really good way to create a VARIETY of users that maybe test out all the bits you may have setup, is manually.  Manually you might see what happens to users with different roles, users who put garbage in the fields, who do strange things etc